# Custom mobile keyboard in unity

Tags: unity, input, mobile, keyboard

I'm trying to create a falling word typing game like z-type.

[I have used the code provided here](https://github.com/Brackeys/Falling-Words-Typing-Game) — but it's is only for keyboards:

```
public class WordInput : MonoBehaviour {

    public WordManager wordManager;

    void Update () {

        foreach (char letter in Input.inputString)
        {
            wordManager.TypeLetter(letter);   
        }    
    }
}
```

I want to implement this on mobiles as well. So I have created a mobile keypad using a canvas and buttons for alphabets but I'm unable to link it to words shown on the screen.

Answer (score 1):

It's reading letters from `Input.inputString`. So all we have to do is provide our own alternate input source.

```
public class CustomInput : MonoBehaviour {

    string inputThisFrame = "";
    
    // Call this method from your on-screen buttons.
    public void Type(string text) {
        inputThisFrame += text;
    }

    // Expose text the same way Input does.
    public string inputString {
        get {
             if(inputThisFrame != "")
                 return inputThisFrame;

             // Fall back on built-in input.
             return Input.inputString;
        }
    }

    // At the end of the frame, clear the buffer
    // so we start from scratch next frame.
    void LateUpdate() {
        inputThisFrame = "";
    }
}
```

Now you can:

1. Place an instance of CustomInput in your scene
2. Wire up your on-screen buttons to report their typing to the CustomInput instance
3. Modify WordInput so it takes an instance of CustomInput and asks for its `inputString` instead of the built-in Input.

   The fallback we added above ensures the regular keyboard still works, when presentz which helps with testing.

Comment: Thanks for the response @DMGregory    ...I'm still having issues with the keypad. I have created the CustomInput script and added it to the main camera. Then I added the CustomInput script to the button's "On Click" function...Modified the wordinput script as follows :                                                                                                   
     foreach(char letter in customInput.inputString)
        {
            wordManager.TypeLetter(letter);
        }  But get a null reference error to the foreach line....Any advise on how to rectify this?

Comment: Did you remember to assign WordInput's customInput instance, or did you leave it as null?

Comment: no @DMGregory, I haven't added...not sure how to do that..this what I have:public WordManager wordManager;
    public CustomInput customInput;

 // Update is called once per frame
 void Update () {
        foreach(char letter in customInput.inputString)
        {
            wordManager.TypeLetter(letter);
        }
  
 }

Comment: Assign the customInput reference in the Inspector.